# The href link is not clickable

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

The text's colour has changed but it doesn't seem to be clickable I am not sure where I am making this mistake I am very new to HTML and CSS

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height:800px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
 }

 .centered {
    position:absolute;
    top: 430px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <img src="4.jpg"alt="Snow">
     <div class="centered"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That anchor is correct, and it is indeed clickable and points to google.com as expected.

Comment: See here, the link is clickable: https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/oNgLyRQ

Answer (score 0):

The following full HTML code for your reference. In SharePoint, you can add the code into script editor web part in a web part page to check if it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        height:800px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
    }

    .centered {
        position:absolute;
        top: 430px;
        left: 300px;
        width: 100%
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
     <img src="4.jpg" alt="Snow"/>
     <div class="centered"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the href link still not clickable, you can using IE/chrome F12 to check if some errors occurs when click the link.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `s` in the `http`. It is https://www.google.com/ not http://www.google.com/

`s` shouldn't matter but for some reason putting `https` in the link. Worked for me.

`http` https://jsfiddle.net/fg7tbwzL/3/

`https` https://jsfiddle.net/fg7tbwzL/4/  (worked)

Comment: This is not accurate. `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` is just fine. In fact, Google will automatically redirect any http request to https.

Comment: Agreed but in jsfiddle it didn't redirect to google.com. Putting `s` in the http seems to work.

Comment: That is because of jsfiddle protecting a combination of non-secure elements on a secure page. Open your browser console and you will notice this message: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.google.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Furthermore, create a blank html document on your computer with nothing but `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>` and open it. The link will work :)

Comment: @MichaelRodriguez That I was not aware of. Very interesting. I don't know why it isn't working for this person.